# Strange situation in entity framework query

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm using entity framework with a visual studio 2013 application and SQL Server 2008R2.
I have a table on the database :

> id == name == quantity
>
> 1----- nm1---- 3
>
> 2------nm2---- 7

Now , I have this code

```
Dim query1 as ienumerable(of Table1)

query1=(From t in context.table1 where t.quantity>0 select t).Tolist
query1.First.quantity-=3
query1=(From t in context.table1 where t.quantity>0 select t).Tolist
```

Now, in the first line, query1 contains 2 objects nm1 and nm2 with quantity 3 and 7.

In the third line, query1 contains 2 objects, but nm1 has quantity 0.

**My question is** :
if the third query get the items from the database , the nm1 should have the quantity=3. why this item has quantity 0?

And also , if the query get the items from the local cache , the query on the third line should not contain **nm1** at all because on the local cache nm1 has the quantity=0 and the query has t.quantity>0.

Thank you!

Comment: It's taking the value from the local cache.

Comment: @IvanStoev If is taking the value from local cache , the query on the  third line should not contain nm1 at all , because the query has the t.quantity>0 and on the local cache nm1 has the quantity 0.But the query contains the nm1 but with the value 0.

Comment: It's caching. Once your Id is fetched it is does not go back to the database unless you [bust the cache](http://codethug.com/2016/02/19/Entity-Framework-Cache-Busting/). I agree it seems it should still apply the where clause but apparently it does not. Try adding `AsNotTracking` if you don't want that behavior.

Comment: Yeah, I know, it's a weird behavior - database is queried, but then materialized objects are replaced with the cached. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48417229/rollingback-vs-refreshing-vs-reloading-entity-data/48419126#48419126

Comment: @IvanStoev What I want is that when I need the changed values , to be able to read from the cache but not to have at all the "nm1" object because the quantity is 0 and the where clause will exclude it. How can I achieve this ?